# To multithread or not to multithread - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I am currently experimenting with a JavaScript shooting game similar to space invaders.  The way it is coded now, either the projectile with move or the ship.  Anyone that has played the original will know that this isn't good.  I remember going over multithreading in my Java class and was wondering if this was the right way to go or is there another way to do it?  For instance:

```
Thread Move start;
Thread Move run;
Thread Shoot start;
Thread Move run;
Thread Shoot run;
Thread Shoot end;
Thread Move run;
Thread Move end;
```

Comment: Is this javascript or java? Or are you trying to port java to javascript?

Comment: http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java

Comment: @RobertHarvey its ok, we forgive you

Comment: Javascript is single threaded. So you cannot multi thread it.

If you are not using javascript, retitle your question. Posted this as an answer, which it is, if he's using javascript, but others seemed to disagree.

Comment: @75inchpianist - JavaScript _used to be_ single threaded. These days we have web workers (for what they're worth).

Comment: @ryan - are you sure that tag edit was valid? I think OP is asking about how to code in JavaScript the way he is used to coding in Java.

Comment: For a game like this you should use a loop that handles all the animation/movement in that frame.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, I posted this just before class and the professor decided to have a "technology free" session.  I meant this to be for JavaScript.  I looked at the tag and saw that I put Java instead of JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WebWorkers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CGAQFjAE&url=http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/&ei=Pn5LUemaDYbqiwKogoH4Ag&usg=AFQjCNGX25uwxo9Rzd6FF8yjKKYjn3PPSQ&sig2=I_SDu4QS8V5jSRcl-jFpjg&bvm=bv.44158598,d.cGE) in Javascript, but they act nowhere near the same as a true multithreaded environment, as in java. You will have to take a different approach to your game development, using a sort of round robin technique to update the logic of your game all under the same thread, sorry. :( The support added for threading in javascript is still very hoaky, and almost a gimmick in my opinion, the only one who is kind of there is Chrome, because you do not necessarily copy all data passed to the thread. Here is why threads in javascript are hamstrung:

1. No true access to the dom
2. Most if not all (depending on engine) data must be copied to other thread, meaning that if you want to process a huge amount of data in the background, you will have to perform a copy on that data first
3. Errors on WebWorkers are not yet always completely obvious (Sometimes you get random, hard to understand errors)

With that WebWorkers have great potential, but for me, their use is severely limited by the limitations placed on them at this time. Maybe you can find a clever use for them in your game.

Comment: Since this is a basic game, I will probably just make a loop that will simulate multithreading by detecting if two inputs are selected and moving one then the other.  It will be significantly longer, but I think it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, JavaScript was single-threaded, so using threads like you are used to in Java was not feasible. A relatively recent addition to JavaScript is web workers ([spec here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-workers/current-work/)) which provides true multi-threading. However, [support among browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) is somewhat variable, you are restricted on what can be done by a worker thread, and communication between threads is painful.

You can also use something like [Clumpy.js](http://www.tumuski.com/code/clumpy/overview/) to simulate asynchronous execution.

Whatever you do, it's important to not block the main thread. The entire browser window becomes unresponsive.

Comment: A solid, informative answer.  The only reason I am not selecting this as my answer is because I got an idea that snowballed from @Ryan.